# Communication betwen processes on different nodes

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have to create distributed publish subscribe system, but I'm stuck at the very begining beacuse I can't figure out how to exchange messages between processes on different nodes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message to a process on another node is the same as inside local node. The problem is only to determine its pid. This can be made by introducing a registar which maps some known data to pids. The registrar may be a process with well known name or address storing those mappings inside, a bunch of processes to spread load or a database.

For a start you can try distributed gproc.